# Resolving Collaboration Issues with AWS Amplify in a Multi-Environment Setup

Tags: aws-amplify, aws-amplify-cli, amplifyjs

I'm part of a team developing a web application using AWS Amplify. We're facing challenges in our collaborative environment, particularly with our CI/CD processes.

Context:

Each team member has their own AWS account and a separate Amplify environment.
We maintain several staging environments that are deployed automatically, in addition to a production environment.
Issue:
When a team member makes significant changes (like removing an API and a Lambda function) and merges these into our main Git branch, it leads to synchronization problems. Other team members, when pulling the latest changes, encounter missing configuration files/function files which was removed.
This requires them to manually run commands with amplify cli to remove the function/api.

Specific Questions:

How can we ensure that significant changes (like API and Lambda modifications) are integrated across all team members' environments?
Are there best practices or specific configurations that we are missing?
Could our current CI/CD process be contributing to these issues?
Any insights or suggestions to improve our workflow would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Why not build shared resources with the CDK?